# CSV File Not Being Converted to an Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to import a csv file as an array in python using the ""numpy.loadtxt"" method. It keeps returning ""ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''"" despite there not being any blank cells in the csv file. Here is my code

```
import csv
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

array = np.loadtxt("HIP Only 2.csv", dtype=np.float32, delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Without at least a sample of the file we can't help.  Doesn't the error show the problem string?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some Non-numerics in the cells, which may be related to specified strings or errors created due to unsuccessful formula in some cells e.g.  `#DIV/0!` in excel files which is  appeared when corresponding cells have not filled or numbers divided by zero. `numpy.loadtxt` is for using when **no data is missed**. If getting array is the main goal, not using `numpy.loadtxt`, `numpy.genfromtxt` is more flexible and could be used instead e.g.:

```
array = np.genfromtxt("HIP Only 2.csv", dtype=np.float32, delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
```

Hope it e helpful.

Comment: I looked through the file and deleted all of the rows that have text. The program is detecting a string of "" which I can't find.

Comment: @Anti-Thorium If your problem does not work by my answer, please provide your problematic file.